# DataFrame groupBy when each group has a difference

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm attempting to `groupby` several columns in a `DataFrame` and only keep the rows where a specific column changed values.

Here is a sample of the dataset

```
Id  Type    Size    StoredAt
107  1       20    2019-08-01
107  1       20    2019-08-02
107  1       20    2019-07-31
107  1       20    2019-07-30
107  3       20    2019-07-29
108  1       20    2019-08-01
108  1       20    2019-08-02
108  3       20    2019-07-31
```

What I'm attempting to do is `groupby` so I only have two rows that shows when the type went from a 1 to a three. Here is what I want the `DataFrame` to look like.

```
Id  Type    Size    StoredAt
107  1       20    2019-08-01
107  3       20    2019-07-29
108  1       20    2019-08-01
108  3       20    2019-07-31
```

All I have so far

```py
dataFrame.groupby(['Id', 'Type', 'Size'])['Id', 'Type', 'Size', 'StoredAt']
```

Which isn't returning what I'm expecting.

Comment: Are you trying to detect the point at which the change occurs (eg the 1 and 3 should be immediately next to each other? Or just the first example of a 1 or a 3 in that group?

Comment: The latter, I want the first time Type is a 1 and the last time Type is a 2

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just keeping the first example of a 1 or a 3 within that group. In that case you can use the following to give your desired output:

```
df.groupby(['Id', 'Type']).first().reset_index()
```

This assumes that your dataframe is sorted on the "StoredAt" column. If it's not you will need to do a sort before hand.

An alternative would be to use drop_duplicates using only the subset of columns which should be unique combinations (Id and Type) in this case. This would be:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Id', 'Type'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `drop_duplicates` work for you

```
df.drop_duplicates(['Id','Type'])
Out[256]: 
    Id  Type  Size    StoredAt
0  107     1    20  2019-08-01
4  107     3    20  2019-07-29
5  108     1    20  2019-08-01
7  108     3    20  2019-07-31
```